# Dynamically Loading LI's in JQueryMobile 1.0

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've just updated my project from jquerymobile 1.0a1 to version 1.0.

I've encountered a problem with dynamic content. Based on an ajax search I populate an unordered list with list items. Previous the following code refreshed the list so that all the styling appeared correctly:

```
$('#myContent').find("ul").listview();
$('#myContent').find("ul").listview('refresh');
```

However as of 1.0 this no longer seems to work. 
The list appears but the styling is all wrong and the data-theme on all the elements gets ignored.
Has anyone come across a similar issue with updating and come across the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> **Updating lists**
>  If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create
>   any nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the `refresh()` method only affects new nodes appended to a
>   list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already
>   enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if
>   you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list
>   item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated,
>   replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

if #myContent is the listview you can do this:

```
$('#myContent').listview('refresh');
```

if #myContent is the page you can do something like this:

```
$('#myContent').trigger('create');
```

> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction**
>  Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method
>   that some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw
>   markup that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be
>   used on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved by replacing your 2 lines of code with the following:

```
 $('#myContent ul').listview('create');
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't think Leon's answer works. I tried it in desperation and got this error: > no such method 'create' for listview widget instance

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue. The reason you are getting things all messed up is you are initalizing and refreshing the element multiple times. I noticed I had 2 different functions running that would call .listview('refresh') on the same element. After I took one out the themes and data went back to looking normal. Also are you getting any JS errors?

EDIT:
To be more specific you are calling `.listview()` somewhere in your code 2 times which is initializing it twice. I would wait to before you page is loaded to run the refresh so you only call it once.

Another thing you could do is check if the element is initialized already or not so you don't do it twice. Just check the element or in some cases the parent to see if the class `ui-listview` is present.

```
var element = $('#myContent').find('ul');    

if ($(element).hasClass('ui-listview')) {
  //Element is already initialized
  $(element).listview('refresh');
} else {
  //Element has not been initiliazed
  $(element).listview().listview('refresh');
}
```

Just an FYI you can chain those events to look like `$('#myContent').find('ul').listview().listview('refresh');`

Comment: Thanks for the response that's more or less what I have but at best it only loads in some of the styling and paddings and margins in particular are all wrong.

Comment: @jkilbride Please post your entire code on jsfiddle then. Like said it is more than likely you are calling a double init on that element.

Answer (score 0):

It cand be achived through.

```
$('#myContent').listview('refresh');

The below snippet shows you to load data from xml and dynamically create a list view.
 function loadData()
 {
    $.ajax({
    url:"BirthdayInvitations.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) 
    {
       $(xml).find("event").each(function() 
       {
       $("#mymenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a" ">' + this.textContent + '  </a> </li>'); 
       });

       $("#mymenu").listview('refresh');
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is related to ur question http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/jquery-mobile-twitter-app/ and this one also http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/ipad-online-dictionary-app/

In first example i am using listview('refresh'); method and in second example i am using 
$(document).page("destroy").page();